# A sliding pager like < 1 2 3 4 >

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using a View (grid with 4 columns).

I need to customize the pager at the bottom to see the next pages.

I want a pager like this: "< 1 2 3 4 >", each number is a View page.

The arrows should slide the numbers to right or left.. i.e. "< 3 4 5 6 >" and they should not have any effect on the pages.. the user can change page only when he clicks on a number.

I was wondering if there is a Drupal module for this, or I should focus on jQuery plugins..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

customize theme_pager or theme_views_mini_pager (if ajax pager was selected) in your template.php

Comment: are you sure this is going to help me ? I don't need to change parameters, but the layout of it. For example, I now need 2 missing functionalities: (1) the current item should always be visible in the center of the slider and (2) if I have less than 4 pages they should be centered in between the arrows.

Comment: Also, I need to remove the '...' dots and display all the page numbers even if these are more than 10. thanks